# NiFi 1.4 queue shows millions of files and 0 MB

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I am facing a problem during the last days with a NiFi flow using HDFS List and Fetch processors.

The queue between them shows more than one million flow files and a total of 0 MB size.

This is very confusing. If I tried to see one of the files I am able to list them and if I click on the info bottom I can confirm the file size, but it seems to be empty. Back pressure is set to 100K, therefore I could not understand the number of files.

I tried restarting NiFi and dropping the files but the problem returns again.

Hier a screenshot of part of the flow:

[image]

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListHDFS` or any `List*` processors for that matter don't carry the actual content. They just generate a flowfile that references the files present in the configured path or resource. These flowfiles are empty, in the sense that it doesn't have the actual content but they just carry key metadata associated to the files, like the path, name, owner, last modified time, etc. as part of their flowfile attributes. You can view them by listing the queue and navigating to the `Attributes` section and all these metadata will be there.

`List` processors in NiFi are supposed to be used together with their `Fetch` counterparts. So you use `ListHDFS` with `FetchHDFS`, `ListS3` with `FetchS3Object` and so on. The Fetch processors use the attributes (of the incoming flowfiles) to actually read the files or resources. This is the reasone why you see `0 bytes` in the flowfile outputs of any `List` processors

And even in the screenshot that you have provided, `FetchHDFS` read the incoming flowfiles from ListHDFS and output the files which carry the *actual* content, as visible in the success queue from the attached screenshot (`4.93 GB`)

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the size would be 0 bytes, but back-pressure can only be engaged after the queue has exceed the threshold. So if ListHDFS produces 1 million flow files during a single execution, it won't be until after the 1 million flow files are in the queue that NiFi can then detect that back-pressure should be engaged.